# Compiler error "expected a type" in protocol definition

Tags: objective-c, compiler-errors, protocols

I have two files defining protocols, for implementing the observer pattern, and I'm getting a compiler error from one of them.

```
// ObserverDelegate.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@protocol ObserverDelegate <NSObject>
@required
@end


// ObservableDelegate.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "ObserverDelegate.h"
@protocol ObservableDelegate <NSObject>
@required
-(void) addObserver: (ObservableDelegate*) observer; // ERROR ON THIS LINE WHEN COMPILE
@end
```

I only have .h files for `ObserverDelegate` and `ObservableDelegate`, there are no corresponding .m files.

The error says "expected a type" in ObserveableDelegate.h on the line `-(void) addObserver: (ObservableDelegate*) observer;`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`ObservableDelegate` isn't a type, it's the name of the protocol. You can't use it as the type of a method parameter. If you want to require that the argument to the method conform to that protocol, you express it like this:

```
- (void)addObserver: (id<ObservableDelegate>)observer;
```

This says that the method takes any object (`id` is the "generic" pointer) which conforms to `ObservableDelegate`. You can use a more specific type than `id` if you want and you know, for example, that the delegate should always be a `UIViewController` subclass as well.

Comment: oh i see, thanks, you saved my life but please tell me in java, i can do just what i did..thanks, its only objective c is like that

Comment: cool thanks, but i got another error when adding an element of id<ObservableDeleagate>) observer...incompattilble pointer types sending '__autoreleasing id ' to parameter of type id